# jQuery "on" handler does not fire on newly inserted widgets

Tags: widgets, jquery, wp-admin

I have a jQuery script attached to the widget.php page via an add_action('admin_footer') call.

The jQuery executes fine on widget items that were in place when the page loaded. However, on newly installed widgets (widgets that are added to the sidebar after the page has loaded), the handler does not fire.

Any ideas how to work around this issue?

```
if ($pagenow == 'widgets.php'){
    add_action('admin_footer', 'my_load_widgets_script');
    function my_load_widgets_script()
    {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('.toggleExtras').on('click', function(e){
            jQuery('.extras').toggle();
            jQuery(this).text(function(el, old){
                return old == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced Options";
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="toggleExtras">Show Advanced Options</span>
```

Comment: How are you adding widgets "after the page has loaded"? Also, so far this does not sound WordPress specific which would make it off-topic per the [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off topic here, but for the sake of solving your problem:

For delegated events, the  [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) part should be

`jQuery(document).on('click','.toggleExtras', function(e){`

Comment: ^ This is exactly how I handle binding events onto dynamically added items, good answer.